# iPhone iOS Exchange not showing new folders

Tags: iphone, ios, email, folders, exchange

for some reason my iPhone's Exchange account won't add new folders that I created in Outlook. Emails come in, but not new folders. I am not sure how long I've had this problem so I can't pinpoint to an iOS update or anything like that.

Things I've looked into:

- PUSH LIST - Everything I've searched and read mentions adding folders to a push
  list, however these new folders don't even appear to add to the push
  list.
- RESET ACCOUNT (works) - The only work around I have to delete the Exchange account entirely
  on the iPhone and then add it again. THEN, I get my new folders.
- TOGGLE EMAIL - Turning off and then back on the "email on/off slider" in the account
  settings does NOT help either.

Here is what I'm running:

- iPhone 4S w/ iOS 7.1.1
- Windows Server 2003
- Exchange Server 2003
- Outlook 2010

Any thoughts?

Thanks